# Why do nth roots (radicals) have closed forms whilst other polynomial roots do not?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

The nth root function - $\sqrt[n]{a_{0}}$ - may be seen as an arithmetic operation (the inverse of the $pow(x, n)$ function) but it can also be interpreted as computing the roots of a specific class of polynomial - polynomials of the form $x^n - a_{0} = 0$ (which are cyclotomic if n is prime). Galois theory is a direct result of the fact that we only allow such roots (or "radicals") to have a closed form notation, whereas general polynomial roots are given no such notation and are thus, in general, "unsolvable by radicals" if the polynomial is of quintic degree or higher. Why is this?

As far as I am aware, such nth roots are not any easier or faster to calculate numerically than the roots of a general polynomial. The same methods are applied to both problems which involve the computation of irrational numbers. So what is special about nth roots as compared with the roots of other polynomials? Is there a logical reason that only such "pure" nth-root polynomial roots have a closed form or is just an accident of history?

In particular, I am considering a simple generalization of the nth root function from a binary function to a k+1-ary function that takes the last k coefficients of a polynomial as parameters, not just the very last coefficient. It would be an interesting question to see the resulting Galois theory for different values of k other than k = 1.

Note: The Bring radical or ultraradical is similar to this idea and can be used to solve otherwise unsolvable quintic equations, but is specific to quintic polynomials.

Comment: $n$th powers have one big numerical advantage over a random polynomial root: They can be calculated using the binomial series.

Comment: Wow, really? I thought Newton's method and its refinements were the most efficient way to compute nth roots. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Another advantage of $n$th powers is that they're bijective over the non-negative reals, which is what makes their inverses well-defined. In order to define inverse functions for more general polynomials, you'd at least have to first solve the non-trivial problem of where the inverse is allowed to go,

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been explicit that I was talking about polynomial roots over the complex numbers and not the real numbers. The proposed generalization of the nth root function has a bijective inverse defined as the computation of k symmetric polynomials in the roots of the equation. Every unique set of coefficients defines a new set of roots and vice versa and thus the inverse is well defined.

Comment: Re your last comment: Not quite. Every ordered set of coefficients gives rise to an unordered set of roots. Or in other words, any permutation of the roots leaves the sequence of coefficients of the polynomial untouched. The relation is $n!$ to one.

Comment: Bring radicals, hypergeometric series and what not have the property that they depend on a converging series of some kind. So they depend on having a topology around. What if the field of coefficients does not have a topology? Ok, I do see that your point is that the same applies to $n$th roots. That is IF you want to calculate numerical values of the roots.

Comment: Thanks, Jyrki, you are absolutely right re:ordering. Thanks for catching me on that. 

I don't want to calculate numerical values, I just want to know why only $\sqrt[n]{x}$ has a valid closed form. I was also wondering if a notation like $\sqrt[n]{a_{k}, ..., a_{0}}$ could be used to denote a generalized k-ary radical and if not why not.

Comment: A Galois theoretic point in favor of the $n$th roots is that if an extension of fields $L/K$ is cyclic of order $n$, and $K$ contains the $n$th roots of unity, then it is easy to prove that $L=K(\root n\of a)$ for some $a\in K$. This is a basis for Kummer theory (the result must have been known to Galois, and in the case $n=3$ to Cardano - though in different language). This is the smallest Galois group an irreducible degree $n$ polynomial can have. At the other is the generic case of a symmetric group $S_n$. There is no such clean description of those.